# accessing property in another class

Tags: ios

I have 2 classes, say for A and B. 
I have a mutable array _arrayOfPaths in A class now I am trying to access that array in class b. 
Like below:

```
A *testModel = [[A alloc]init];
 NSMutableArray *array = [testModel.arrayOfPaths mutableCopy];
```

Now when I `NSLog` this newly made array then it shows null. 
if I print `testModel.arrayOfPaths` then it shows null too.

My questions are:

1. Why its showing null?
2. How can I access `_arrayOfPaths` in B class?
3. Do I need to use inheritance for it? B is already inheriting
   `UITableViewController`.
4. Is Multiple inheritance supported by objective c?

Comment: u want to pass array such like A to B ??

Comment: yes i want to use array of class A in class B

Comment: how you are moving from class A to Class B?   Here, your are simply creating a new instance of A, instead of accessing the existing instance of A to fetch the array.  So that only it is showing null value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.  Here, your are simply creating a new instance of A, instead of accessing the existing instance of A to fetch the array inside B instance. So that only it is showing null value.**

**2.  See this code for 2nd question....**

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface ClassA:UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfPaths;

@end
```

**ClassA.m**

```
@implementation ClassA

@synthesize arrayOfPaths = _arrayOfPaths;

    -(id)init
    {
       self = [super init];
       if(self)
       {
        self.arrayOfPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];

        //Delegation process
        ClassB *bInstance = [[ClassB alloc] init];
        [bInstance setAReference:self];

        //Do your stuff of presenting ClassB instance here.....
       }
}
@end
```

**ClassB.h**

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@interface ClassB:UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) ClassA *aReference;

@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
@implementation ClassB

@synthesize aReference = _aReference;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Array from class ClassA %@", self.aReference.arrayOfPaths);
}
@end
```

ClassB ViewController should be instantiated by ClassA only here.

**3.  You need to use the delegates concept to acheive your requirement. See the above example code**

**4. objective -c won't support multiple inheritance.**

Answer (score 1):

1. It's showing null (probably) because arrayOfPaths isn't yet initialized.
2. Make a public property called `arrayOfPaths` in class A's header file
3. No
4. No

In A's .h-file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfPaths;
```

In A's .m-file:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.arrayOfPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: i have initialized arrayOfPaths in class B do i need to initialize it again in class A?

Comment: i do understand array should be public but why you did this all -(id) self = [super init]; and all?

Comment: arrayOfPaths resides in class A as far as I can see. testModel.arrayOfPaths (and testModel is an instance of class A). So where do you initialize it in class B?

Comment: why cant i just initialize it like arrayOfPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; this?

Comment: i did initialize it in class A like this arrayOfPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: -(id)init {..} is code that runs when you do [[A alloc] init]. We initialize the array here so that class B can get it from the public property.

Comment: it will not work if i initialize like this ?arrayOfPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in class A

Comment: "arrayOfPaths" doesn't exist in class A. The array can be accessed via "_arrayOfPaths" or "self.arrayOfPaths" in class A

Comment: yes i can acces _arrayOfPaths in class A perfectly. why i need to initialize it like -(id)init {..} why cant i just initialize it like _arrayOfPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27079/discussion-between-undeph-and-user2189388)

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton class for sharing the data
Check this Singleton class

`MyManger.h`

```
 #import <foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface MyManager : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * array;

 + (id)sharedManager;  

 @end
```

`MyManger.m`

```
 #import "MyManager.h"

 static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;

 @implementation MyManager



 #pragma mark Singleton Methods  

 + (id)sharedManager {
   @synchronized(self) {
    if(sharedMyManager == nil)
     sharedMyManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
   }
  return sharedMyManager;
 } 

 - (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
 return self;
 }
```

You can access your array from everywhere like this

```
 MyManager * sharedArray = [MyManager sharedManager]

 [sharedArray array]
```

Comment: There are other ways to pass data across classes; Singletons are not used for data sharing across classes.

Comment: i thought question asked about data sharing between view controllers

Comment: Again; What are view controller? They are CLASSES.

Comment: then When should we use Singleton Classes? @Matt

Comment: The objective of the Singleton pattern as defined in *Design Patterns* is to "ensure a class has only one instance, and provide a global point of access to it"

Comment: You can very well do the thing as your answer suggests with singleton; but, it's not the purpose for which singletons are used, my friend.

Comment: Also, by implementing data access like this (as in your answer), will expose data to non-relevant classes, too. That again loose the essence of OOPS - Data encapsulation. I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Matt Yea got it ! thanks alot for the info buddy.. you opened my eyes!! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27081/discussion-between-matt-and-vinu1991)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are pushing B view controller from A class. Make a property and before pushing do this

//allocation B oject and array
objBViewController.arra =self.arr;
//pushview controller

And objective don't support Multiple inheritance but we achieve this by makeing Protocols/Delgates. Google it or read this link

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA45894

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question #2.
You can access the property through class method.

**ClassA.h**

```
 @interface ClassA

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayInClassA;

    @end
```

**ClassA.m**

```
import "ClassA.h"

NSMutableArray *array1;

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize arrayInClass A = _arrayInClassA;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.arrayInClassA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
    array1 = self.arrayInClassA;
}
+(id)returnArrayInClassA
{
return array1;
@end
```

**ClassB.h**

```
@interface ClassB:UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray arrayInClassB;

@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
import "ClassB.h"
import "classA.h"
@implementation ClassB

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
self.arrayInClassB = [ClassA returnArrayInClassA];
}
@end
```